# Profiling cache misses of a routine

Tags: c++, caching, profiling

I want to profile the cache misses (rate) of a specific routine in a C++ program. I know some profiling tools but they don't seem to quite satisfy me.

To the best of my knowledge:

*gprof* can produce call graph and code coverage, but it doesn't include cache miss profiling.

*valgrind* (cachegrind) can profile cache misses but seems only for the whole application.

*oprofile* indeed has a symbol-based output. But I'm a bit confused: say if procedure A() calls B() (maybe library or system call), and cache misses occur inside B(), is it attributed to A()? After all I would like to count the cache misses during the whole execution of A().

A last question. OProfile requires restarting the daemon for each new session. Suppose I want to profile my program with a number of runs --- with a set of different parameters and inputs. How can I do it in an automated way? Is there some way like inserting gettimeofday() into the code to get the cache statistics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your cache-misses in a particular function are what is significant, then using either cachegrind or oprofile should work just fine. If your cache misses in that function are not significant for the whole execution of the program, why are you bothering?

From memory, but it was a couple of years since I used oprofile, but you don't need to restart the daemon, just using the "reset my data" (`opcontrol --reset`). Since oprofile is system wide, you can simply run a script with your multiple testcases - oprofile will split data per process, but if you have high cache-usage in any particular function, that should show up on the list of cache-misses. And if it doesn't show up, then your code isn't missing in the cache.

The way I've been doing it is to write a script that does the `opcontrol --reset --start event=CPU_CLK_UNHALTED:400000`, then whatever program I'm testing, and then `opcontrol --stop --save=oprofile.result`.

Note that oprofile is statistical and sample based, so you can't measure single cache-misses, and it records the address where the cache-misses counter reached the limit. So you can have a situation where, if you have a "limit" of 1000 cache misses, you get 999 cache misses in function A, and then a single cache miss in function B, function B is "credited" with the cache misses. However, assuming you don't have extremely pathological code, you will get your cache miss recordings in the areas of code that miss in the cache.

Comment: Thank you @Mats . As I'm doing this for academic research purpose, I need to profile the particular routine anyway. You mentioned that it is impossible to measure the exact cache miss counting since oprofile is sample based. But is it reasonable to get an estimate by multiplying the sample number with the "limit"?

Comment: Oprofile gives the cache misses as a count of "Hits" (which is how many times, at that place in the code, that there was an interrupt for that measurement) and a percentage of the total (for convenience). Of course, if you know the limit, you can calculate back the number of cache-misses. Cachegrind will give more accurate measurements, as it simulates the memory accesses (but it's a lot slower to run). If the code is simple, you could always manually "pretend to be the proecessor and the cache".

Comment: I see. So in terms of counting cache misses, cachegrind is more accurate than oprofile because it is **simulating** instead of **sampling**, right? But it seems I still have a trouble. My program is multithreaded. I've just checked cachegrind's spec and it says it treats threads differently from usually. So the result may not be useful. Is it true?

Comment: You are REALLY trying to do something impossible, aren't you? Yes, that complicates things. Valgrind, if I understand correctly, will serialize threads (run one thread at a time) under some conditions. I'm not sure of the exact details, but it does indeed change the behaviour. Are you sure you've understood the task correctly, because to me it sounds "unlikely to be solved" (at least with any accuracy).